# Noise trap - Interior Scene with no glass materials

Tags: rendering, noise-reduction

I want to get rid of the noise but I can't for the sake of god find out what is causing it.
I am using an HDRI.
I am not using glass materials.
I blocked all the HDRI light with objects apart from 2 windows (no glass, no geometry, just 2 big openings).
Here is a picture (32 samples)
:[image]
(I am new to blender but I am very familiar with 3d environments)
(HDRI is hidden by ''world-> ray visibility-> camera (uncheck)'' but checking it doesnt make any difference anyways)

EDIT:
My question here lies on, why does this happen? The problem is solved, I can just increase the samples and activate the denoiser. The problem I have with this is that previewing with 32 samples is different than previewing with 100 or 500 samples. At one point I added a glass material and it acted as a noise trap and after removing the material, the noise trap persisted. I want to know why that happened.
[image]

Comment: 32 samples is way too low. start with 500

Comment: Worth reading as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70183/how-to-avoid-grainy-renderings-in-cycles/70186#70186

Comment: Not gonna link more threads, you can find a lot about this under 'Get rid of/ Reduce Fireflies'

Comment: @WhatAMesh those are not fireflies.

Comment: Isn't light portals a thing anymore?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/502/increase-cycles-speed-for-interior-render

Comment: I know 32 is too low and I know there might be a solution on those threads but I don't want to try everything until it works. I had a scene, I previewed the render with 32 samples and it worked just fine, then I added a glass material to the windows and it became noisy. I removed the material (I even removed the windows) and it stayed noisy as you can see. I want to know why that happens.