# light not passing through window

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I modeled my room using an Add-on called Archimesh to make more easily windows doors and so on when I finally modeled the room and rendered it I faced 2 problems which are:

1. I added a sunlight that passes through the window of the room there is light in the room however it is really dim and the glass material of the WINDOW is not transparent I watched how BlenderGuru made the material for the glass and mine still is solid despite the fact that light is coming through the room.
2. The next problem is rendering I used the Cycles render engine to render the room and got a really grainy image in the sampler I tried increasing the render value to 1000 still looks like crap.

[image: Render of my room]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33017/what-does-light-portal-mean and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/502/increase-cycles-speed-for-interior-render?rq=1 might help.

Comment: Please use a descriptive title.

Comment: @Keavon Dude I told you I have no 3D experience.

Comment: Hello and welcome, please keep only one question per post so we can answer them, make as many as needed. Also please search before posting, all of these are very frequently asked and have already been answered before many times. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/how-can-i-make-a-more-realistic-glass-shader

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/how-to-avoid-noisy-renders-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles